# ubinary type in Perforce

Tags: perforce

What is this file type exactly and how does it differ from `binary`?

It seems to be automatically assigned to `.zip` and `.jar` files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It turns out `ubinary` means uncompressed binary, and this makes sense since trying to further compress a `.zip` or `.jar` is pointless.